# Referring to results in past or present tense

Tags: tenses, past-tense, present-tense, past-vs-present

When I am reporting the status of some results, should I use past tense？ For example, would it be correct to say, when the test result was announced in the past, "Your test result was failed. I am sorry about that." I know we have "backshift" in English. Does this mean that I can use present tense or past tense in this kind of sentence? For example:

> Your test result is failed. I am sorry about that.
>
> Didn't you have my message? I had your message. [or] I have your message.

Am I right that it depends on what the time is that is in the speaker's mind when thinking of the action—whether he/she is thinking of now (he/she still has the message) or of the action in the past (he/she had it already)?

Comment: _You failed your test_, _Didn't you **get** my message_ and _I **got** your message_. I think this question would feel better at home on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

Your first example, mixes present and past tense. *is* and *failed*... regardless of which tense you pick, you should be consistent. Instead of

> Your test result is failed. I am sorry about that.

I would write

> You failed the test. I am sorry about that.

And instead of conjugating have with

> Didn't you have my message? I had your message. [or] I have your message.

I would suggest you use the verb *receive* instead

> Did you receive my message? I received yours.

Comment: I thought "failed" is an adjective. That's why I put it in the sentence. "Your test result is failed. I am sorry about that."

Comment: @Kam Verbs have tense. In the US, you take a test (I think I've also heard [sit for an exam](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sit+for+an+exam)). And, you may *pass* or *fail* a test you take. Finally, that means those tests can be *passed* or *failed*. Hope that helps.

Comment: How's about the "backshift". Am I correct about it?

Comment: @Kam Wikipedia says [backshift](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backshift) is *(grammar) The changing of the tense of a verb from present to past in reported speech.* So I'm curious how you would *backshift* an adjective. "How about the *backshift*?" Kam asked, I replied what about the *backshift*.

Comment: You could certainly say *Your test result is 'Failed'.* just as you could say *Your result is 45%*.  Outside that rare construction, it is best not to make the result the subject of a sentence.

Comment: @tim what kind of test? A failure, or even a F. But "failed"? *I keep trying to think, but nothing happens*.

Comment: Surely it is conceivable for the possible results of an exam to be 'Distinction' 'Passed' or 'Failed'? I agree that the capital is necessary (which is why I put it in).

Comment: @TimLymington That smells like a *post hoc ergo propter hoc* argument to me. Admittedly, I studied for my exams (or revised if you prefer) so I am certainly not authoratitive on failing grades.